# Autocomplete custom google search engine for places

Tags: android, google-app-engine, search, autocomplete, google-places-api

Hi I am implementing a search for an android application.
I need to do an autocomplete search engine for only a certain type of places (like restaurants). And I have no idea how to start, if anyone could show me an example of a custom search engine or give me some tips, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to implement Google Place API for Finding Restaurant,Nice Documentation is Given here regarding finding a restaurant around nearest place in.Read this document carefully.https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

After Implementing This document You need to implement autocomplete this may help you https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android, and if in case it may not help you than you might have to apply some your own logic and do it